# mod rewrite with lang parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd just like want:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?lang=en » www.domain.com/en/

www.domain.com/category.php?lang=en&cat=namecategory » www.domain.com/en/namecategory/
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/$1
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^.]+)/$ scale.php?lang=$1&categoria=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have no problem with the index page, but with the category page, if i do a print_r($GET) i have:

```
Array
(
[lang] => en
[categoria] => namecategory//namecategory
)
```

So the url is rewrite fine, but then i have problem with variables.
Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^.]+)/$ scale.php?lang=$1&categoria=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/$ [L]
```

You need the conditions to apply to all 3 of your rules, so you need to duplicate them for each of the 3. You also need the language matching rules to happen before the rule which matches everything (`(.*)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^.]+)/?$ scale.php?lang=$1&categoria=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Seems perfect! Thanks you very much! I spent too many hours on it without solve it, i think i should resum study mod rewrite stuff.